# Bit order of ADV7125 ADC

Tags: adc

Datasheet: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADV7125.pdf

Assuming R0, G0 and B0 are the least significant bits of each channel, but cannot find it specified anywhere in the datasheet explicitly.

Is there a convention for this that the higher the bit number, the higher its significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "R0, G0, and B0 are the least significant data bits."

Found this on page 10, table 7.